# How Do I Implement Plug-Ins in Obj-C/CocoaTouch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, plist, nsdictionary

I need a simple, lightweight, approach to support a plug-in system in an iOS app I am writing. Nothing fancy. This will not be exposed to the user but rather is a productivity aid for my development of roughly 100 small (~50 lines of code) modules of code that I allow the user to select from.

I currently am leaning heavily on a plist/NSDictionary approach with a category on NSDictionary to additional functionality. The plist is a dictionary of settings specific to functionality that a corresponding plug-in with communicate with. I now want to add the plug-in name as a target/action pair. This is where I am a bit unsure of the best approach. How to I specify this target/action pair? Clearly I don't want 100 subclasses. Perhaps a protocol/delegate design?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invocations and operations are your friend. If you make a custom operation that is passed logic data it can either use invocations or directly call the modules. With this approach you can add numerous operations to the queue.

Comment: Some more context. These 100 method variations are gesture recognizer behavior. So tap/pan/rotate gesture + the logic within the gesture handler. I want to somehow specify this within my plist. This sure feels like a delegate is the way to go, no? But then, how do I package it as an element in my plist?

Comment: Hang on, just discovered NSSelectorFromString. That feels about right. I will simply add the string name for the selector. Done and done?

Comment: yes that's pretty much it, you store a selector name in a file. I will say again though that you may find it helpful to do something like this: [aInvocation setSelector:NSSelectorFromString(userSelectedString)]; [aInvocation invokeWithTarget:currentTarget];

Comment: to elaborate on this idea, imagine a graphics app where you have a view that you can draw to and you have a table with a bunch of tools to use on the drawing view. the table delegates to the drawing view's controller that it should change it's current tool. when the user selects a tool the view controller looks for a group of selector names with the selected tool as their key (put the strings in an array, then put the array in a dictionary).

Comment: it then sets the selector for several invocations that it stores (it would store one invocation for each gesture recognizer if each gesture recognizer does something different). in the viewDidload method of your view controller you would add the gesture recognizers to your view and set their selectors to methods in the view controller that call for example [tapInvocation invokeWithTarget:currentTarget]; this way, you don't have to mess with the gesture recognizers's actions (imagine a subview with more gesture recognizers), plus you can use selectors with return values.